# Get source then POST

Tags: php, post

I'm relative new to PHP (I have some more experience with Java) and I've discovered curl for php.
I created some functions to send post data to an url and get the content from that page but now I need to send post data to an url that have a 'security token' that changes at every page refresh.
When I get page source and get the security token and send with post parameters it is incorrect because it changes.
How can I get source, get security token and send post (with curl) with the correct security token?

(sorry if I made mistakes writting english)

Comment: In what format is the security token given? Also, post some code.

Comment: the security token is a hidden input in a form
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="67bea0ed9f116ab154b90c81ec5a01bb5240ba7793f4a3.50725856">

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: If in cookies, specify a proper cookiejar & -file, if in html / input's, load in `DOMDocument` & search for them. Edit: `DOMXPath`, search for `//input[@name="securitytoken"]/@value`

Comment: You need to talk about how you receive and handle the security token.  Show some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this being form submit, that it looks like you are trying to automate, my guess is that the remote server is looking for that token value in session to compare to to prevent against session hi-jacking attacks.  If this is the case, you will likely need to save the session cookie that is sent, and send the session cookie back with each request (along with the regenerated token of course).

Comment: How I save cookie session?
I'm trying adding this to my function:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');